# JToolbar frontend submit value on click

Tags: joomla, components, frontend, jtoolbar

I'm building a joomla component and I can't find a solution to the following. In my front end I'm using the joomlas build in class JToolbar to handle events on click like edit, delete so one.

```
            <form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php');?>" method="post"
                name="termForm" id="adminForm">

                <table class="stripeMe">
                    <tbody>


                    <thead>

                        <tr>
                            <th>Begriff</th>
                            <th>Definition</th>



<?php if ($user->authorize('com_glossary', 'edit', 'glossary', 'all')): ?><th>Published</th> <?php endif; ?>    

        </tr>
                    </thead>

              <?php foreach($this->items as $i => $item): ?>

            <tr> 

                <td>

                <span class="title"><?php echo $item->tterm; ?></span>

                    <?php if ($user->authorize('com_glossary', 'edit', 'bearbeiten', 'all')):?> 

                       <?php echo $this->getEdit(); ?><?php endif; ?>

                </td>

               <td><?php echo $item->tdefinition; ?></td>
                 <?php if ($user->authorize('com_glossary', 'edit', 'bearbeiten', 'all')): ?>
               <td><?php echo $this->getPublished(); ?></td> <?php endif; ?>    


           </tr>
               <?php endforeach; ?>

    </tbody>
    </table>

                <div>
        <input type="hidden" name="task" value="" /> <input type="hidden"
                        name="id" value="" onclick="submitbutton(<?php echo count( $item->id ); ?>);" /> <input type="hidden"
                        name="option" value="com_glossary" /> <input type="hidden"
                        name="controller" value="bearbeiten" />


        <?php echo JHtml::_('form.token'); ?>
    </div>
            </form>
```

I would like to pass to id of the selected row to the sub-controller on button event and I don't really know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Here you have some useful tips about using JToolbar on the frontend http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_use_the_JToolBar_class_in_the_frontend

I have done it once in the past, and from what I remember I did some tricks in order to make it work.

1.) Firstly remove the "id" input and add the following one at the end of your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="boxchecked" value="0" />
```

2.) Secondly make sure Mootools is attached to the source

3.) Finally: There, where you started your foreach loop, after "**tr**" tag add another table column:

```
 <td><?php echo JHTML::_('grid.id', $i, $item->id ); ?></td>
```

Don't forget to create a column heading in **thead** for this column.

These steps will create a checkbox in the first cell of every row and make the form able to send selected field's **id** with request.

**edit:**
tbody tag is in wrong place, it's supposed to be after **thead** tag. Also there is no use of attaching events to hidden input as they won't be triggered

Cheers

Peter

Comment: Yes I was trying that as well but even like that I'm getting the last value from the loop.